# Making a view controller not be in the tabbed view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I am making an app with a tab bar controller connected to a navigation controller which both lead to a collection view. The collection view then segues to a view controller. However, the view controller has a tab bar at the bottom because the tab bar controller is connected to the navigation view. How to I make the normal view controller not be included in the tab bar but still be in the navigation controller? Here is my storyboard: (sorry for confusing description)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmJHO.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: You're welcome.. can you please vote up the answer as well.. Much appreciated !!